# Javascript hoisting with variable and function

Tags: javascript

```
var a=2;
function a(){};
console.log(typeof(a));
```

I am wondering why the result of the above code is `number`. I know the `var` is hoisted but isn't it already at the first line of the code? so why the type of a is still a number instead of a function?

Comment: `function` is hoisted above `var` and then you redeclare it as a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `function a(){}` is actually hoisted, which you can see if you log `a` at various points:

```js
console.log(a);
var a = 2;
console.log(a);
function a() {
    console.log('hi');
}


console.log(a);
```